# RegEx to get numeric value and values with range

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx to match the following format:

```
3
7.3
5.7 (2.2-10.4)
```

I want to check in JS if the given value i.e. `5.7 (2.2-10.4)` is valid. And in PHP I want to split the string to get all three values (if there is a given range).

That means I have to check for a simple numeric value (int and float) or a numeric value followed by a range like `(d-d)`

My attempt:  `/^(\d+)\s\((\d+)\-(\d+)\)$/`

Comment: No. I don't see the duplication of my question. I tried it by myself, but I need some help to correct my attempt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your attempt, does not count for negative values

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s*\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)-(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\))?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/194)

Comment: But `3 (25)` would also be valid, which isn't. `3 (2-5)` would be valid. If there is anything after the first value, it has always to be brackets with a range.

Comment: Thanks. Last question for understanding: How do I have to change the regEx to accept just integer values? I tried `/^(\d+)(?:\s*\((\d+)-(\d+)\)$)?/gm` but this doesn't work properly. The string should be invalid if there is any nonnumeric character as it is given for decimals.